# Disambiguating local class from Firebase renamed class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an app in Swift 3 that uses Firebase. I've created my own class called `User`. I'd like to use both that class and Firebase's `User` class. Firebase's `User` class used to be called `FIRUser` but was renamed in Firebase 4 (i.e., `FIRUser.h` with `FIR_SWIFT_NAME(User)`).

Now I don't know how to use each independently. Whenever I use `User`, my code thinks I'm talking about my `User` class (which makes sense). But how do I refer to Firebase's `User` class when I can't use `FIRUser` anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue when upgrading to *Firebase 4* ;) I did something already suggested by MacLean answer but opted for a *project wide* solution instead.

In a `Firebase.swift` file, I added the following `typealias`:

```
// 
// Firebase.swift
//
import FirebaseAuth

/// Class `FirebaseAuth.User` conflicts with `MyApp.User`.
typealias AuthUser = FirebaseAuth.User
```

Then, elsewhere in the project, I simply use `AuthUser` when using the Firebase class and just `User` for my own type. The above `typealias` has `internal` visibility and, as such, is available across your app code.

Depending on your codebase size, this might provide a better tradeoff than using a *per-file* solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just `import class User`, which will make all future reference to `User` within the file refer to the one you've imported.

You could also potentially use a `typealias` on one of them if you want to change they way one of the classes is called within a single file.

Generally though, it'd be best to just rename your `User` class to something more specific though, sadly :<

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. If I want to import the FIRUser class and use that throughout the file, what do I import? I can't import FIRUser because that doesn't exist anymore. Where is it?

Comment: `import class FirebaseAuth.FIRUser` . If you look into it, you can see that they just specified `User` as it's Swift name with the line, `FIR_SWIFT_NAME(User)`